# Google App Engine: Deployed Source doesn't have Local updates

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm working with Google App Engine in Eclipse w/ JSP pages in Windows 7.
I already have an app deployed and working, but I am unable to make changes to it for some reason.

If I make changes and debug locally, my localhost page is showing the changes that I implement.
While I am not getting any errors in the deployment, the same changes that work on my local debug are no longer showing up, so I can't update my app.
I thought updating the version number might help, but I had no luck with this.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you deploying the same version (as specified in appengine-web.xml) as the default version that is running on your app?  If not, you'll have to access your new deployment at http://newversion.appname.appspot.com, or change your default version in app engine to your newly deployed version.

Comment: Wow, you totally nailed it, thank you. A couple more questions: 1) Is there any way to get the current deployment onto my normal appspot url? It is kind of awkward to have the version number prefix. 2) Do you know why they do this? This seems totally unneccesary and it just set me back a long time...

Comment: I realize now that you already answered my follow up questions. Thanks again for the insights!

Comment: Hi, I'm kinda new to SO, but I think I get points if you somehow put a checkmark on the answer to this question.  I'd appreciate it.  I don't actually know how you'd do that though :P

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problems too, especially when the changes concerned the static pages. Some little things to check:

- If you have set an `expiration date` in your app.yaml, your browser cache could be holding the file.
- If it’s specific to the online contents, it could be an intermediary cache (such as a squid server) serving the outdated contents, in which case you’d have to flush the cache to get the new version.

You could start by checking the log on the GAE console to see if the request is received by the server, that would help you debug.

Another trick, if you’re being served an outdated version of `http://yourapp.appspot.com/index`, try and pass a dummy argument to force the browser to update the version, for instance : `http://yourapp.appspot.com/index?p=1`

Comment: Hi qdii, thank you for your insights. I checked my app.yaml's, which have a line "expiration: 365d", so I'm guessing this is not the problem. Also I tried your last trick to no avail, unfortunately.

Comment: In the GAE console, everything compiles and it tells me "new version is ready to start serving." I will look into the squid cache option, thank you for the recommendation.